# How To Get Current Derivative Block ID From Within hook_form_alter Function in Drupal 8?

Tags: php, oop, drupal, block, drupal-8

I'm building a custom Drupal 8 module which will make changes to a Webform based on the derivative plugin ID. I'm able to get the derivative plugin ID from within the `build()` function of the base block using **$this->getDerivativeId()** but It's not clear on how I can call `getDerivativeId()` from `mycustommodule.module` where I'm using `hook_form_alter`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I've tried so far without success:

1. I first tired `$this->getDerivativeId()` directly from `hook_form_alter` but I get an error

   > "Using $this when not in object context"
2. Then I tried creating a new function in my base block class called "getCurrentBlockId()" where I would try to return the `getDerivativeId()` value but it forced me to make the function static and once I did that I could no longer use `$this->getDerivativeId()`.

   ```
   $block_id = \Drupal\transcode_profile\Plugin\Block\TranscodeBlockDerivative::getCurrentBlockId();
   ```
3. I also tried to creating a constructor to save the derivative block ID to a variable which would be accessible across the scope of my module but failed at that as well.

In summary, I can use `$this->getDerivativId()` at...
`\Drupal\transcode_profile\Plugin\Block\TranscodeBlockDerivative`
but need to use at...
`\Drupal\transcode_profile\transcode_profile.module`
and not sure how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing much about your setup, but I believe you can achieve this by instantiating the plugin in question because you cannot call non-static methods statically and you can't use `$this` in non-object mode respectively.

Assuming you are after a block derivative you could try:

```
/* @var $manager \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockManagerInterface */
$manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');

/* @var $block \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface */
$block = $manager->createInstance($block_id);

$derivative_id = $block->getDerivativeId();
```